# Hide Page navigator in a jquery grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How I can hide View text and page navigation in a jQuery grid navigator?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`viewrecords`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option to hide the view text:

```
viewrecords: false
```

You can set the following pager options to false to disable page navigation:

```
pgbuttons: false,
pginput: false,
```